# Drupal 7: Cannot see Module Changes

Tags: 7, caching

Is there any kind of cache applied to the Modules?

I am developing a module but I am not able to see the last changes I made (Adding a new Role programmatically), even after cleaning all caches.

install code (update):

```
function nutrition_install() 
{

    //Create New Role
    $role = new stdClass();
    $role->name = 'nutricionist';
    $role->weight = 1;
    user_role_save($role);

  node_types_rebuild();
  $types = node_type_get_types();

 // add the body field to the node type
  node_add_body_field($types['meal']);

  // Load the instance definition for our content type's body
  $body_instance = field_info_instance('node', 'body', 'meal');

  // Configure the body field
  $body_instance['type'] = 'text_summary_or_trimmed';

  // Save our changes to the body field instance.
  field_update_instance($body_instance);

  // Create all the fields we are adding to our content type.
  foreach (_meal_installed_fields() as $field) {
    field_create_field($field);
  }
  // Create all the instances for our fields.
    foreach (_meal_installed_instances() as $instance) {
        $instance['entity_type'] = 'node';
        $instance['bundle'] = 'meal';
        field_create_instance($instance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to rename your module, probably your module name is the same as a hook somewhere in the system.

Comment: The name of the module is 'Nutrition' and I did installed it before, but the last lines of code regarding the role are not working.

Comment: For some hooks you have to reinstall your module to see changes. [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) is good helper for this (`/devel/reinstall`).

Comment: I added the code of the install function, hope it helps

Comment: See my update. To keep is short, `hook_install` is run when the module is installed and never since.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are using some sort of opcode cache, the code in your module itself won't be cached. Some hooks will only be run in certain cases and/or have cache. Most likely this is what is giving your problem.

A possible solution would be to uninstall and reinstall it again. (don't just disable the module, but uninstall it). Doing so removes a lot of the information about the module and could fix the problem.

If you gave more detail on the code/hooks you were using, a more detailed answer could be given.

**Update**

[`hook_install`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) is run when the module is installed. This is a once per install only, so changing the code after the module is installed won't do anything. A new install is the only way to test the changes, after proper cleanup have been made.

Comment: I disabled the plugin, removed the folder, cleaned all caches, copied and enabled again, But still there's no changes.

Comment: @XaviColomer Did you uninstall it. Did you clean up old data? (delete the role and fields) You should do this and you will see the effect.

Comment: Solved. At some point there was a previous installed version of the Module. I had to remove it manually from the database in the 'system' table. Thanks for all the help.